# ASP.Net 1.1 Prevent Cookieless session XSS attack with config not working

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, xss, websecurity

I have been tasked with fixing a XSS vulnerability that takes advantage of the cookieless session feature in **ASP.Net 1.1**. The attack could be done like so:

> [https://example.com/AnyPageInTheApplication.aspx/(A('onerror='alert%601%60'testabcd))/](https://example.com/AnyPageInTheApplication.aspx/(A(%27onerror=%27alert%601%60%27testabcd))/)

So far I have tried the following values in the web.config file:

```
<pages validateRequest="true" ....

<sessionState cookieless="false" ....

<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" ...
```

none have prevented the alert to be displayed once I navigate to any page using the above example.

**UPDATE**: If I look in the Network tab on Chrome's dev tools, it seems that the application considers the last part of the URL as a resource since it is listed on the calls as a document with a 200 status.

Any help to prevent the JS code to execute using this technique will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: ASP.NET 1.1 ?? Is this on Windows 95? Seriously, who in the world is still using ASP.NET 1.1?

Comment: @Jamal - It is a legacy application that still needs to be maintained.

Comment: See if the following helps (HttpOnly Cookies):  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpOnlyCookiesOnASPNET11.aspx